# Bound on the coefficient of a $P$-adic decomposition of a polynomial in term of the sup norm

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let :

- $P=\prod_{i=1}^d(T-\alpha_i)\in \mathbb C[T]$ such that for $i\neq j$, $\alpha_i\neq\alpha_j$ ;
- $Q=\sum_{k=0}^nQ_kP^k\in\mathbb C[T]$ with $\forall k,\ \deg(Q_k)\leqslant \deg(P)-1$ be the $P$-adic decomposition of $Q$ ;
- for $r>0$, $D(P,r)=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon |P(z)|\leqslant r\}$.

Is that true that for all $k$ and $i$, $|Q_k(\alpha_i)|r^k\leqslant\sup_{z\in D(P,r)}|Q(z)|$ ?

It's true when $P$ is of degree $1$. In this case, the $P$-adic decomposition is just the Taylor expansion and the inequality follows from Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: The simplest thing to try, in the case where $r$ is small enough that $D(P,r)$ has $d$ connected components, is to apply the Cauchy integral formula (in its non-circular form) to the integral of $Q/ P^{k+1}$ over the boundary of the $i$th component. Do you know if this works?

Comment: I have tried this too but didn't manage to get the result. In part because the residue theorem on a connected component didn't gives you $Q_k(\alpha_i)$ but somthing that also depend $Q_{k'}$ with $k'<k$. But maybe I made a mistake